# How to implement custom Tensorflow.js models into webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow.js

I would like to create a website that can classify different types of cars. I have managed to get the website working to use the mobile net model, but I would like to use a custom model that I trained in google colab and then converted into javascript. Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Here is the javascript code:

```html
// Defining Variables
const webcamElement = document.getElementById('webcam');
let net;
var webcamrunning = false; // Flag, indicates if webcam-prediction is running or not
var bw = document.getElementById('butwebcam')
var bi = document.getElementById('butimage')


// App that predicts image
async function app() {
console.log('Loading mobilenet..');
const uploadJSONInput = document.getElementById('upload-json');
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(tf.io.browserFiles([uploadJSONInput.files[0]]));
// Check if model loaded, if not, load it.
  if (net == undefined)
      {bi.innerHTML = 'Wait for Initiation...';

      net = await model.load();
      console.log('Sucessfully loaded model');
      bi.innerHTML = 'Predict'}
else {console.log('Model already loaded')};

// Make a prediction through the model on our image.
const imgEl = document.getElementById('output');
const result = await net.classify(imgEl);

    document.getElementById('console_pic').innerText =
    `Prediction: ${result[0].className}
    Probability: ${Math.round(result[0].probability*100)} %
  `;
}



// Function that activates (starts webcam app) and deactivates the Webcam-Prediction
function start_webcam(){
  if (webcamrunning == false)
      {app_webcam();
      }
  else {webcamrunning = false;
      bw.innerHTML = 'Activate Predicting';
      };
};


// Setup Webcam
async function setupWebcam() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const navigatorAny = navigator;
  navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigatorAny.webkitGetUserMedia || navigatorAny.mozGetUserMedia ||
      navigatorAny.msGetUserMedia;
  if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true},
      stream => {
        webcamElement.srcObject = stream;
        webcamElement.addEventListener('loadeddata',  () => resolve(), false);
      },
      error => reject());
  } else {
    reject();
  }
});
}



// Webcam application
async function app_webcam() {
console.log('Loading mobilenet..');

// Check if model loaded, if not, load it.
if (net == undefined)
   {bw.innerHTML = 'Wait for Initiation...';
   net = await mobilenet.load();
   console.log('Sucessfully loaded model');}
else {console.log('Model already loaded')};

await setupWebcam();
webcamrunning =true;
bw.innerHTML = 'Stop Predicting';

while (webcamrunning) {

  const result = await net.classify(webcamElement);

  document.getElementById('console_vid').innerText =
    `Prediction: ${result[0].className}
    Probability: ${Math.round(result[0].probability*100)} %
  `;

  // Give some breathing room by waiting for the next animation frame to
  // fire.
  await tf.nextFrame();
}
}
;
```

Here is the html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'/>
    <input type="file" id="upload-json" src="C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ImageClassifier-master\model\model.json"/>
    <!-- Load the latest version of TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow-models/mobilenet"></script>

    <title> Image Classifier with MobileNet </title>
 </head>

  <body>

    <img style='margin-top: -6px; z-index: 19;' id="header" height ="320">
    <h1 style='margin-top: -35px'> What car is that?</h1>
    <br>
    <hr/>
    <br>
        <em> <strong> </strong> </em>
        <br>
         <br>

    <hr/>
    <br>
    <h2> Upload your own Picture</h2>
    <!-- Upload Function with File Preview -->
    <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" height="200"
        onchange="document.getElementById('output').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">

    <!-- Predict button, calls predict function in Javascript -->
    <button id="butimage" onclick="app()"> Predict! </button>


    <!-- Window for Picture Preview -->
    <div class = "window">
            <span class="helper"></span>
            <img class="center" id="output" alt="your image" src = "img/example.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class = "result" id="console_pic">Result</div>
    <br>

    <hr/>
    <br>


    <br>

    <br>
    <br>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```